# Need Assistance With a Simple HTML/PHP Web Page

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a simple PHP web page that asks the user to input a domain and then click the SUBMIT button. When the user clicks SUBMIT the page should display the name of the domain that they typed in.
I have XAMPP installed on my computer and I have a file named test234.php in my htdocs directory. This PHP file contains the following PHP and HTML code:

```
<?php
$message = "";
if (!isset($domain)) {
    $message = "<br>Enter a domain<br>";
} else {
    $message = "You typed in $domain as the domain";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Some title</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center">
Some title

<?php print $message ?>
</h1>

<form method="POST" align="center">
Domain: <input type="text" name="domain"><input type="submit" align="center"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I type in a domain and click SUBMIT it just reloads the same page asking for the user to type in a domain. I want it to output the text "You have typed in $domain as the domain" but can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up $_POST and $_GET

Comment: You never assign `$domain` so it will always be unset. `$_POST['domain']` on the other hand though...

Comment: `if (!isset($_POST['domain']))`

Comment: In the very old days of PHP and register_globals, form variables were created automatically. Today you need to use $_POST, $_GET, or $_REQUEST

Comment: Thank you very much! That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 3):

The value of `$domain` was never declared. If you would like to get form data you need to use the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_REQUEST` object(s), in your case you are using the `post` method in your form so instead of `$domain` use `$_POST["domain"]`:

```
<?php
$message = "";
$domain = $_POST["domain"];
if (!isset($domain)) {
    $message = "<br>Enter a domain<br>";
} else {
    $message = "You typed in $domain as the domain";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Spencer. I appreciate it!